# error nodejs require its no define

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

*hi, i got this error when i run my local serves,*
*thanks*

```
code html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <label>Your ID:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="yourId"></textarea><br/>
    <label>Other ID:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="otherId"></textarea>
    <button id="connect">connect</button><br/>

    <label>Enter Message:</label><br/>
    <textarea id="yourMessage"></textarea>
    <button id="send">send</button>
    <pre id="messages"></pre>

    <script src="index.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var getUserMedia = require('getusermedia')

getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function (err, stream) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  var Peer = require('simple-peer')
  console.log("conectar")
  var peer = new Peer({
    initiator: location.hash === '#init',
    trickle: false,
    stream: stream

  })

  peer.on('signal', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('yourId').value = JSON.stringify(data)
    console.log("peer on signal 1")
    console.log(data)

  })

  document.getElementById('connect').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var otherId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('otherId').value)
    console.log("conectar")
    peer.signal(otherId)
  })

  document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById('yourMessage').value
    console.log("getElementById")
    peer.send(yourMessage)
  })

  peer.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("peer data")
    document.getElementById('messages').textContent += data + '\n'
  })

  peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
    console.log("stream")
    var video = document.createElement('video')
    document.body.appendChild(video)

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video.play()
  })
})
```

server.js

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');




var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('privateKey.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.crt')
};

var mundo= https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

  console.log(req.url)



  if(req.url === '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync("./index.html"));
  }

  if(req.url === '/index.js') {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
    res.end(fs.readFileSync("./index.js"));
    };


  if(req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.end(fs.readFileSync("./favicon.ico"));
    };


  res.end();
  console.log("listening to port 8000");

});


mundo.listen(8443);
```

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxWBB.png)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack overflow. Please look properly when you add the code. Please add the image embed, so people answering to your question doesn't need to open separate window or go outside SOF. Also please be as much specific as possible. In other words - read first How to ask question on stack overflow.

Comment: @DominikBucher New users cannot embed images.

Answer (score 0):

You are using require in a client side script (in index.js). require is not supported in browsers.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971583/node-style-require-for-in-browser-javascript) for more information.