# Running JavaScript with 'require' from developers Console on Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there an easy way to execute a javascript on Chrome browser when the JS require several files,

ex. to run the unit test of https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/bs58 or https://github.com/kronolynx/pgp-word-list-converter on my browser directly from chromebook is that doable?

Comment: No it is not, as `require()` is synchronous so you would have to "install" all the dependencies before.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971583/node-style-require-for-in-browser-javascript