# How to package multiple ES6 classes for vanilla browser javascript development?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I need to use a number of co-dependent ES6 classes in a web page, where development will be continued. For various reasons, the remainder of the development must happen in a browser-compatible environment. That is, I will be writing 'vanilla' javascript to be run in a script tag that uses these existing classes. I will NOT be using any more ES6 features developing this part of the JS.

I've already tried using babel and webpack to transpile my code into browser-friendly javascript. However, webpack renames and minifies the javascript so that it is virtually impossible to do any more extended development. Optimally, the classes that I defined in my ES6 code will remain exposed (as plain prototypal functions) as interfaces.

As an example, suppose I have some ES6 class `BinaryOperation` and a class `Number` (I know this exists in JS, but just as an example). These classes are defined in two separate JS files and have their own constructors. The "Number" class is a dependency of `BinaryOperation` and is imported. `BinaryOperation` has a number of functions in the class. I would like to be able to bundle both classes and their functionality into a single browser compatible file. This file would let me create `BinaryOperation` objects in my browser code using the `new` keyword, like I would for any non-es6 object prototype. What tools will help me accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser may have something to do with your question, but handling of dependencies is a more complicated story. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971583/node-style-require-for-in-browser-javascript has some ideas, but the synchronous->asynchronous change is not really addressed there.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, I've found [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en) which includes a babel plugin. This combines all es6 files into a single module and then converts all of the code to ES5 compatible JS.