# Receiving 'require not defined' in browser when implementing Mapbox with node

Tags: javascript, html, css, pug, mapbox

I'm in the middle of a course and currently trying to implement mapbox.js . I have followed all of the instructions directly from the mapbox documentation but am receiving an error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
<anonymous> http://localhost:8000/js/mapbox.js:3
```

Here is my mapbox.js file:

```
var mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');

mapboxgl.accessToken =
  'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnJhbmF1c3QiLCJhIjoiY2tnOHVibGllMDVuYjJ5cHFmbmpucndwZSJ9.KBzYV-QSHSChEb6QJpNpdg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
});
```

and I am appending to the head of my base file inside a separate .pug file :

```
block append head
link(href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet')
```

[image]

Comment: Which documentation are you reading? I can't see any mention of `require` here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

Comment: I just added a picture of the instructions given to me from their website. Thanks for your help

Comment: I can't look at the documentation for context if I only see a screenshot of a small portion of it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is a function in node js (server side) only and not in the browser.

See the answer to using require in the browser here:
[Node-style require for in-browser javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971583/node-style-require-for-in-browser-javascript)

### or

Alternatively, just add script tag linking to the mapbox js files and remove your require statement.

So add this to your html:
`<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>`

Then change your code to be:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnJhbmF1c3QiLCJhIjoiY2tnOHVibGllMDVuYjJ5cHFmbmpucndwZSJ9.KBzYV-QSHSChEb6QJpNpdg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
});
```