# HTML onClick node js function loading 'require' another module in the onClick function not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, onclick

I have code like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onclick Event</h2>

<p>The onclick event triggers a function when an element is clicked on.</p>
<p>Click to trigger a function that will output "Hello World":</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  const os = require('os')
  let hostName = os.hostname()
  alert(hostName);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code works when I remove:

```
  const os = require('os')
  hostName = os.hostname()
  alert(hostName);
```

I however need to load a module in this function that is being used for the onClick event.

Please note that I am a noob to javascript.
Any and all assistance / guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

for those coming to this page, check:
[Node-style require for in-browser javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971583/node-style-require-for-in-browser-javascript)

Comment: As per the duplicate, you can’t load a module which depends on Node.js in your browser-side code. If it depends on Node.js then it depends on Node.js.

Comment: ahh okay cool, make sense.
I will find another way around it. thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```js
 const button = document.getElementById('btn');
 const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    
    button.onclick = function() {
        demo.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
    };
```

```html
    <button id="btn" >Click me</button>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
```

If you want to load a module you need to show some of your node.js code as we don't see what that looks like and what you want to render.

I suggest reading the documentation of Node.js and EJS.

Comment: that is it my bud, should load the OS module, if I want to perform some OS functions on button click.

Comment: regarding `I suggest reading the documentation of Node.js and EJS.`

what documentation exactly?

your answer isn't an answer?...

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html 

const os = require('os'); should be placed in the node file.  The os module provides operating system-related utility methods and properties. It doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: okay, so where should it be placed if I want to perform OS operations on button click?

Comment: eg: I want to see the hostname when I click the button.
`let hostName = os.hostname()` and `alert(hostName);`

Comment: that may not be the exact OS functions, but just as an example to help get a proper answer